# Javascript, better way to write an if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a concise or better way to write this condition without having to use so many `||`.

```
if (myVar != 'A' && myVar != 'B' && myVar != 'C'){
   ...
}
```

Comment: `if (['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(myVar)) { }`

Answer (score 1):

You can also express it like an array,

```
if (!['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(myVar)) {
  // if myVar is none of the values in the array
}
```

edit: added negation to grab the opposite case as your example

Comment: Although it would need to be negated as all the OPs conditions are !=